# Silverlight: Exception with ListBox and nested collection

Tags: silverlight

help would be very appreciated.

i have a listbox defined in the MainPage.xaml which a bind to a collection of nested objects (boxes).

```
<ListBox x:Name="MyListBox"
                 ItemTemplate="{StaticResource NestedDataTemplate}"/>
```

The box:

```
public class Box
{
  public string BoxName { get; set; }
  public ObservableCollection<Box> Boxes { get; set; }
}
```

I fill each child collection of each box with a single box and I do that up to 15 times, so that the hierarchy contains up to 15 levels.

Box
-Box
--Box
---Box

...... 15 times

In the handler of the loaded event of the MainPage.xaml.cs the collection is populated like so:

```
 ObservableCollection<Box> boxCollection = new ObservableCollection<Box>();

 Box lastBox = new Box();
 lastBox.BoxName = "Box Nr. 1";
 lastBox.Boxes = new ObservableCollection<Box>();

for (int i = 1; i < 15; i++)
{
 Box newBox = new Box();
 newBox.BoxName = "Box Nr. " + (i + 1);
 newBox.Boxes = new ObservableCollection<Box>();
 newBox.Boxes.Add(lastBox);
 lastBox = newBox;
}

boxCollection.Add(lastBox);
MyListBox.ItemsSource = boxCollection;
```

The listbox's items template is a hierarchical data template defined in the resource section of App.xaml.

```
    sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="NestedDataTemplate">
      <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
          <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

      <Border Grid.RowSpan="2" Background="LightGray" Opacity="0.5"/>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding BoxName}"/>
      <ListBox Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Boxes}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource NestedDataTemplate}"/>
     </Grid>
   </sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

When I run the app, it crashes and throws the following exception which can be investigated in the Application_UnhandledException handler in the App.xaml.cs.

The exception:

```
Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.


   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.CheckHResult(UInt32 hr)
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.FrameworkElement_MeasureOverride(FrameworkElement element, Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride(IntPtr nativeTarget, Single inWidth, Single inHeight, Single& outWidth, Single& outHeight)
```

**Note**: If I reduce the amount of hierarchy layers of the box collection, everything works fine.

Please help, I have been struggling for several days. I cannot find anything in forums or blogs.

Thank you